# C# windows formmain thread can't run 2 processes at once/ can't find how to make the work done

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I have trouble making the main thread of my program in my windows form work properly, as it freezes and does not paint my objects for a while. I will explain it with a dummy example.

Let's say we have :

```
a train thread running around a track,
a wagon thread waiting in a place on the same track,
and a main thread painting the objects in the windows form.
```

the train and wagon threads start as follow :

```
public PanelThread train, wagon; 
private Thread thread1, thread2; 

train = new PanelThread(new Point(10, 10),
                             150, Direction.West, Track.track1, pnl1, typetrain.loco,
                             Color.Blue,
                             semaphore
                             );
wagon = new PanelThread(new Point(390, 390),
                             150, Direction.West, Track.track1, pnl1, typetrain.loco,
                             Color.Blue,
                             semaphore
                             );
thread1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(train.Start)); 
thread2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(wagon.Start));

thread1.Start();
thread2.Start();
```

And in the PanelThread class : (the code is specific and only added as asked in comments)

```
public void Start()
    {
        Color signal = Color.Red;
        Thread.Sleep(delay);
        if (this.locwag == typetrain.loco)
        {
            work();
        }
        else
        {
            for (;;)
            {
                if (greenclicked == true)
                {
                    workwagon();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Now, when we click on a button, we launch a function like as follow :

```
private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for(;;)
        {
             if(train.variable1 == true)
             {
                 break;
             }
        }
        wagon.variable2 = true;
    }
```

the variable1 is always false except when the train is on the same place as the wagon (done by checking if the train is at a certain point in a for loop, like at the end of the second passage i.e counter_variable = 2).

Now, the thing is that the for loop is taking all the place in the ain thread and not letting it paint the objects, even though the other thread still work, and the painting resumes after the function is finished.

I tried putting this loop in a function in the train thread launched by the button7_clicked function like this :

```
private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        train.waitingfunction();
        wagon.variable2 = true;
    }
```

But the result is the same as the function waits for the waitingfunction() to be done.

I then thought I would need to completely delegate the work on another thread, using invoke, but I admit I do not understand yet how it exactly works. so I wrote it like this, using invoke on the panel.

```
private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (panel.InvokeRequired)
        {
            panel.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate{train.waitingfunction();}));
        }
        wagon.variable2 = true;
    }
```

As of now there is no freeze anymore but the wagon automatically starts, I am guessing the function never goes in the if statement and I am now completely lost. Any idea on how to work around the problem ?

UPDATE : here is the answer, in the Waitingfunction called waitingwagon in my program, I used AutoResetEvent like this :

```
public void waitingwagon()
    {
        AutoResetEvent autoResetEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
            while (!autoResetEvent.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.1)))
            {
                if (waitinggreen == true)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: ok... from the code you posted, you are not even using more than your main thread ...

Comment: the train uses functions from another cs file called PanelThread, as well as the wagon, I start them up as follow : public PanelThread train, wagon;
        private Thread thread1, thread2;  thread1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(p1t1.Start));

            thread2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(p2t2.Start));

Comment: great ... don't post that in a comment... edit your question ... and include the thread handlers

Comment: but yes, I may not use more than the main thread in the given function, hence why I am lost, how to delegate from the main thread if invoke delegates to the main thread ?

Comment: I just edited as needed, the new code is the first

Comment: still missing: the thread handlers ... `void Start()` on your PanelThread class

Comment: I added it in the question, it is the one that I use and I use a lot of custom types variables so the content won't be clear. I can also add the paint event handler too if you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you want to avoid is for(;;) in your main thread, because that blocks your thread ...

your 2nd thread (wagon) basically has to do nothing, until that status changes, so you could use a event wait handle (e.g. manual/auto reset event) and block your wagon thread with that until that event fires ...

but of course if you have side constraints like "a button has to be clicked" etc you will have to add additional logic to handle that... it's not really possible to provide a working example for your specific problem, since you did not provide a compilable sample, but if you google event wait handles and look for examples on manualresetevent or autoresetevent, you should find something you can adapt

Comment: thanks a lot, I looked into the AutoResetEventHandler, and used it to the called function waitingfunction called waitingwagon, I am putting it in the question